# Compilation error in one case but not the other, when all expressions have same types

Tags: c#, linq

I have a pieces of code:

The method is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<c> Test(){
  var collection = new a();
  IEnumerable<c> bs = collection.Where(item => item.Id > 10).Select(item => item);
  return from item in collection
         where item.Id > 10
         select item;
}
```

(the first two lines compiles fine)

It doesn't compile and fails with:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Stackoverflow.b>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Stackoverflow.c>`

however the code below compiles just fine:

```
return from item in collection
       where item.Id > 10
       select new b(null);
```

since the type of the expression in the select clause is the same I'd expect it to compile in both cases or fail in both.

if I use method syntax instead of query comprehesion and write:

```
collection.Where(item => item.Id > 10).Select(item => item)
```

that too compiles

my question is "[Is there something wrong with the universe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/25/maybe-there-s-something-wrong-with-the-universe-but-probably-not.aspx)" (is this a compiler bug) or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I have no `using System.Linq` so the normal select and where methods is not in play only those below
The code is part of an academic exercise to try and stretch the pattern-based method overload resolution of LINQ. The signatures are deliberately weird/surprising and the where includes a projection though I believe this would generally be a pretty bad idea.

**EDIT**

The definitions of the classes in question and the select extension method

```
public static class Enumerable {
    public static IEnumerable<c> Select(this IEnumerable<b> self, Func<b,b> selector){
        return null;
    }
}

public class a{
    public IEnumerable<b> Where(Predicate<a> predicate){
        return null;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class b{
}

public class c{
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of the method this code is in? What is the type of the variable you are assigning it to?

Comment: I understand the temptation to spice things up with humor and links to blogs you like, but your question is going to be scanned by people who can answer it based on its title, and then for years, it will be scanned by title again by people who may have the same problem, or a completely unrelated problem. You are not helping any of these people. PS: it is unlikely you have found a compiler bug, especially if the supposedly erroneous behavior is to emit an error message. The majority of compiler bugs are to silently emit wrong code.

Comment: What's the definition of `collection`?

Comment: @Oded I've posted the definitions. I don't see that as important to the more general question of "when the types of all expressions are the same why does it fail in on instance and not the other" however :)

Comment: Do you really believed it could be a compiler bug?

Comment: Nearly there - all we need now is the definitions of `b` and `c`...

Comment: @Pascal I agree compiler bugs are unlikely. However in this case I can see why this could happen. The rewritter can in usual cases optimize the call to select a way if the item is returned (with out applying a projection) however in this case where is applying a projection which indeed would is an edge case

Comment: @Ucodia feel free to explain either why the three selects lambdas does not have the same type or why three expressions with exactly the same types should behavior differently when compiled. Both we'll be valid answers

Comment: Is the `selector` parameter in your `Select` supposed to be `Func<b,b>` as you have written? Because the way you're using it suggests it's supposed to be a `Func<b,a>`. How about you scrub evererything you've got and just show us a [short but complete program](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html) **that actually compiles** (except for the one statement that you think should, but doesn't) ?

Comment: @Rune FS, You wrote 3 different expressions, you cannot expect the compiler to process them the same exact way. And also your expressions does different things.

Comment: @Ucodia if you look at the error message it states that the error is due to mismatching of types. The type of each individual expression is the same in all three cases. However in one case the final expression (select item) is ignored. What the expression is doing does usually not affect the type of the expression.

Comment: @AakashM the code I've shown is the actual code and it doesn't compile. The signatures, odd as they maybe are deliberate. Part of a debat on method overload resolution when it comes to query comprehension which is pattern-based and not type based. So the academic exercise that landed me here was to create a surprising linq expression. Ended up surprising my self I guess

Comment: In the body of your `Enumerable.Select`, `selector` is invoked on a `b`, returning a `b`, which is then passed to a `c` ctor. But there is no `c` ctor that accepts a `b`. This means that **it is NOT just `Test` that does not compile**. Seriously, try it: new project, paste in the definitions of `a` `b` `c` and `Enumerable`. Doesn't compile. You would greatly increase your chances of getting help if you make clear: steps to reproduce, expected result, actual result.

Comment: @AakashM you are right there was a .A missing. However the implementation of select is entirely irrelevant to the question. Only the signature is relevant. Any implementation of select with the given signature will fail. Which is now reflected in the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's all about query expressions translation. You might want to look at C# Language Specification 4.0 7.16.2 (or 7.15.2 for C# 3.0) for more details, but in short, expressions like:

```
from x in c
where f(x)
select x
```

Are translated just to

```
c.Where(x => f(x))
```

so your Enumerable.Select wouldn't be called and you'll get IEnumerable<b> as a result instead of IEnumerable<c>. Exactly what compiler is complaining about.

Comment: the section I found it in was 7.15.2 though

Comment: yes, it was 7.15.2 in C# 3.0. I've edited my answer to make it easier to find this part of specification.

Comment: An interesting choice to always remove the select. Rather weird I think since if the where is left out the select is actually executed (7.15.2.3) which in this case results in a different return type in the two cases

Comment: @RuneFS: It'd be needless to call identity Select in normal cases, still "It is important however to ensure that the result of a query expression is never the source object itself", that's why it is called when there is no 'where'. I'd say it would be better to avoid such Select methods as you have and use separate extension method instead, like ConvertToC in addition to ordinary Select.

Comment: I totally agree that from a coding perspective the code I've presented makes little sense. However it came about as part of an academic exercise deliberately trying to write weird/surprising linq. Trying to see how far the pattern-based method overload. resolution could be streched. I personally find it unfortunate that the from item in x where pre select item is not gauranteed to be the same as x.Where(..).Select(..) or where true select is not the same as simply select. I find it violates "least surprise"

Answer (score 1):

As it stands in the error message.

You are not returning the same value as the method signature is.

If you read the error message it stands that it expect C but get B

Comment: Then explain why the exact same code in method syntax does indeed return the type of the method signature. The selct method does indeed return C. If you were correct then why would ...select new b(null) work?

Comment: Read Konstantin Oznobihin answer.

Comment: And I was (indirectly) asking if the error message is correct then what 's the difference between the expressions. Which your answer does not explain

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return from item in collection
    where item.Id > 10
    select (c)item;
```

Seems like all you're missing is a cast from b to c. It might be that using the .Select extension method the compiler can work out this cast automatically. I've seen the compiler using the correct generic method based on the return type. So instead of saying `MyItem item = GenericMethod<MyItem>(input)` one can say `MyItem item = GenericMethod(input)` and the compiler knows which type to use.

Comment: That changes the type of the select expression and would fail because it can't find a matching select method.